# How to bind Services in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Suppose I have a service: `App\Services\FooService`.

To use this service I need to bind it using this statement:

```
$this->app->bind('FooService', \App\Services\FooService::class);
```

**So where do I need to put the above statement?** **In which file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to bind in **AppServiceProvider**

> app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\SocialProvider;
use App\TwitterSocialProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function boot()
  {

  }

   /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function register()
   {
     $this->app->bind('FooService', \App\Services\FooService::class);
  }
}
```